# How do I start a Task with a specific scheduler (eg GUI)

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, scheduler, synchronizationcontext

I am trying to create a `Task` with the TPL. eg:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething());
```

This works fine, but now I want to start it on the gui thread.

I can cache the gui scheduler with:

```
_uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
```

but I can't see how to start a new task using this scheduler. All the examples I can find use `Task.ContinueWith()` to schedule a second task using `_uiScheduler` once the initial task has finished, but I want to create the initial task using this scheduler.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a huge number of overloads of [`StartNew`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew.aspx). [One](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd781658.aspx) of them accepts a scheduler. Simply pass `None` for the other parameters:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething(), CancellationToken.None,
                      TaskCreationOptions.None, _uiScheduler);
```

Comment: D'OH! I could have sworn I went through all the overloads. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

Simple - there are overloads (such as [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd781658.aspx)) of [`TaskFactory.StartNew`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321421.aspx) which take a scheduler as one of the parameters.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething(), CancellationToken.None,
                      TaskCreationOptions.None, _uiScheduler);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
TaskFactory factory = new TaskFactory(TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething());
```